# GitHub workflow to push Docker image to ghcr.io

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, docker-registry

I am trying to push a Docker image from within a GitHub Actions workflow to the GitHub Container Registry (ghcr.io). Here are the steps I've taken:

1. create a GitHub personal access token (PAT) with package read/write/delete permissions
2. logged in locally with this PAT via

   ```bash
   export CR_PAT='...'
   echo $CR_PAT| docker login ghcr.io -u <MY GITHUB USERNAME> --password-stdin
   ```
3. tagged my Docker image with the proper tag and pushed to ghcr

   ```bash
   docker tag texlive ghcr.io/michaellihs/texlive:latest
   docker push ghcr.io/michaellihs/texlive:latest
   ```
4. the image was successfully pushed to https://github.com/users/michaellihs/packages/container/texlive
5. went to the settings page of the package `https://github.com/users/michaellihs/packages/container/texlive/settings` and added the repository in which I implemented the GitHub Actions workflow (`https://github.com/michaellihs/docker-texlive`) as Actions Access with role admin

   [image]
6. I used the following GitHub Actions workflow to build & push my image

   ```yaml
   name: ci

   on:
     push:
       branches:
         - 'main'

   using-an-action
   jobs:
     build-and-push-image:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
         - name: Checkout repository
           uses: actions/checkout@v3

         - name: Log in to the Container registry
           uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
           with:
             registry: https://ghcr.io
             username: ${{ github.actor }}
             password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

         - name: Build and push Docker image
           uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
           with:
             context: image/
             push: true
             tags: ghcr.io/michaellihs/texlive:latest
   ```
7. when I now run the [workflow](https://github.com/michaellihs/docker-texlive/actions/runs/4604932755/jobs/8136515644), I get the following error:

   ```
   #10 ERROR: denied: installation not allowed to Write organization package
   ------
    > pushing ghcr.io/michaellihs/texlive:latest with docker:
   ------
   ERROR: denied: installation not allowed to Write organization package
   Error: buildx call failed with: ERROR: denied: installation not allowed to Write 
   organization package
   ```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to change the workflow permissions in the repository settings is to use [job-level permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) to set write permissions for packages. That has the advantage, that only this job runs with the additional privilege.

```
jobs:
  ...
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
    steps:
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there was one step missing: in the repository that hosts the workflow,

1. go to the repository settings (`/settings`)

   [image]
2. from the menu, select "Actions --> General"

   [image]
3. in the "Workflow permissions" select "Read and write permissions"

   [image]

   **Don't forget to hit "Save" afterwards**

That solved the problem and the image was successfully pushed to the registry.